# NHibernate, i invoke delete but update is invoked automatically!

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

in NHibernate, i invoke delete but update is invoked automatically!!
i use FluentNhibernate Automapping.

Comment: In Soviet Russia, entities delete you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that each of your fields are mapped as NULLable as required.  I've had a similar problem when I've forgotten to mark a field that is NULLable as NULLable in my mapping.